# Create table in kable with special characters in footnote

Tags: r, kable

I have the following problem in R Markdown. I am trying to create a table in kable with special characters in the footnote.

```
\begin{landscape}
{r, echo=FALSE}
m <- fread("/Users/Kati/Documents/TALMA/CZ/Drafts/m_table", select= c(3:7), header = T)
m <- m[complete.cases(m)]
kable(m, "latex", caption = "Probit marginal effects by provider type", booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options=c("scale_down", "hold_position")) %>%
  collapse_rows(columns=1) %>% 
  footnote(number=c("Standard errors in parenthesis. P-values in brackets.",
                       "P-values from Wald-test for $H_0$ : Hazard-ratio = $\frac{Hazard-rate_{{_Weak/Strong}}}{Hazard-rate{_{_Average}}}$ = 1" ), escape = FALSE )
\end{landscape}
```

I get the following error msg.

```
Error in footnote(., number = c("Standard errors in parenthesis. P-values in brackets.",  : 
  unused arguments (number = c("Standard errors in parenthesis. P-values in brackets.", "P-values from Wald-test for $H_0$ : Hazard-ratio = $\frac{Hazard-rate_{{_Weak/Strong}}}{Hazard-rate{_{_Average}}}$ = 1"), escape = FALSE)
Calls: <Anonymous> ... _fseq -> freduce -> withVisible -> <Anonymous> -> footnote
Execution halted
```

What am I doing wrong?